# How to detect when scroll to bottom of LongListSelector or ScrollViewer in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, scrollviewer, longlistselector

I want to load more data when user scroll to bottom of LongListSelector or ScrollViewer (contain longlistselector).
 I have search some stackoverflow question but it's not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good post about Detecting ****LongListSelector’s scrolling** to the bottom. You can have Reference from here [Detecting WP8 LongListSelector’s end of scroll (stretching)](http://nuncaalaprimera.com/2013/detecting-wp8-longlistselectors-end-of-scroll-stretching/)

Try this Implementation for calling calss function:

```
var _list_compress = new WP8PullDetector()
_list_compress.Bind(LongListSelectorName);
_list_compress.Compression += _list_compress_Compression;
```

Comment: but how to use this code for my program? It just provide a class

Comment: OnCompression, ViewportItems, GetRelativePosition, ITweetable get undefined. Can you provide a full sample or write a new article? Thanks

Comment: this can be useful for that https://codepad.ly2314.cc/longlistselector-scroll-to-endtop-detection/

Answer (score 1):

I am using Daniel Vauchan solution with ScrollViewerMonitor from this blog post: http://danielvaughan.org/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Where is also sample code availiable [http://danielvaughan.org/file.axd?file=2011%2f1%2fDanielVaughan.ScrollViewerMonitor.zip](http://danielvaughan.org/file.axd?file=2011%2F1%2FDanielVaughan.ScrollViewerMonitor.zip)

It was developed for ListBox in WP7, but still works fine with LongListSelector in WP8. Just be careful with scenarios which involve Navigation between pages, because this code uses DependencyPropertyListener class and subscribes to listener.Changed event every time your LongListSelector will be Loaded. So you have to manually detach listener.Changed when Navigating from your page.

As an alternative you can try to use Telerik RadDataBoundListBox. It's rather good and supports Infinite loading from the box.

UPDATE:
It seems, that LongListSelector doesn't contain ScrollViewer. ScrollViewer is inside Listbox. However there is ScrollBar inside LongListSelector and its Value Property and ValueChanged event. You can detect scrolling to bottom with scrollbar valuechanged event with checking that ScrollBar Value is more or equals ScrollBar.Maximum. (You can add some constant to improve scroll to end detection).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look a this link from Windows Phone Blog. I haven't tried it personally but have bookmarked it for future. Let me know if it is useful. 
[How to create an infinite scrollable list with LongListSelector](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2012/10/01/how-to-create-an-infinite-scrollable-list-with-longlistselector/)